# Ubuntu 16.04 - MongoDB 3.4.x - Install specific version

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, package, version, ubuntu-16.04

i use the standard install guide for mongodb 3.4 on ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mongodb-org -y
```

This one installs me the latest version of mongodb 3.4.X

But what if i just want a specific version, lets say 3.4.9

Is there any way to just have this specific version installed?

Greetings and Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your last command you should input something like

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.4.X mongodb-org-server=3.4.X mongodb-org-shell=3.4.X mongodb-org-mongos=3.4.X mongodb-org-tools=3.4.X
```